Managing "Reject" Button Access in a Laravel API App using Service and Policy
In my Laravel API project, I have a Service for handling quote rejection and a Policy for controlling access based on application type. Here's how I'm managing access to the "Reject" button in the client.
Service for rejecting a quote
public function reject(Quote $quote): bool
{
    if ($quote->rejected_at) {
        throw new QuoteAlreadyRejectedException();
    }

    return $quote->update(['rejected_at' => Carbon::now()]);
}


Policy for access control
public function reject(User $user, Quote $quote, AppTypeEnum $app): Response
{
    if (!$user->can('reject quotes')) {
        return Response::deny();
    }

    if ($app === AppTypeEnum::CONSUMER) {
        return Response::allow();
    }

    return Response::deny();
}


Controller to handle reject request
public function reject(Quote $quote): JsonResponse
{
    try {
        $this->authorize('reject', [$quote, AppTypeEnum::CONSUMER]);
        $success = $this->quoteService->reject($quote);
    } catch (QuoteAlreadyRejectedException $e) {
        return $this->errorResponse($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }

    return $this->successResponse($success);
}

I have integrated a quote rejection functionality in my Laravel API. The Service (QuoteService) is responsible for updating the quote's rejected_at timestamp and throws a QuoteAlreadyRejectedException if the quote has already been rejected. On the other hand, the Policy (QuotePolicy) controls access to the "Reject" action based on user permissions ('reject quotes' capability) and the application type (AppTypeEnum::CONSUMER).
I know it should be placed in the service, but I also wanted to add it in the policy. In my resource, I have an actions array with 'reject' that returns true or false. This is needed to display buttons in the interface. How can I manage this? Because if I move the check to the policy, it doesn't seem correct, as the button would always be visible when it shouldn't.

Strictly speaking, the policy should only indicate whether the current user is allowed to do something, not whether that something is possible. The check on whether it's possible should be done before the policy is tested. Maybe overkill but you could add middleware that prevents the request from reaching the controller code if the quote is already rejected as accessing a reject route with an already rejected quote seems like a data validation problem.

Yeah have to agree with @apokryfos - you should handle this using a middleware, preventing the endpoint from being reached if the bound object is already rejected. You can throw the relevant exception in the middleware and handle so your user gets a graceful response.
